# Getting error code 247 while deploying django app

Tags: django, docker

I am trying to deploy my Django application to Digital ocean droplets, using the less expensive one, that gives me 512 mb of ram, 1 CPU and 10 gigs of SSD. Then, after I set up everything properly, I run `docker-compose up --build` to see if everything is fine. It launches all. In my docker compose, I use a postgres instance, a redis one and a celery one, and the django application I wrote. If that matters, here is the docker-compose file

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db: 
    container_name: my_table_postgres
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432/tcp
    volumes:
      - my_table_postgres_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=my_table_postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=dev
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=blablabla

  redis: 
    container_name: redis
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6739:6739/tcp
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis-oauth-user-service
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/var/lib/redis/data/

  my_table:
    container_name: my_table
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000
    volumes:
      - .:/api
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

  celery:
    image: celery
    container_name: celery
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: ['python', '-m', 'celery', '-A', 'mytable' ,'worker', '-l', 'INFO']
    volumes:
      - .:/api
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - my_table
    links:
      - redis

volumes:
  my_table_postgres_db:
  redis_data:
```

Then, all starts up quite slowly, but after I try to make a request from something like postman, in the terminal of docker compose, the main process of the django app says that `my_table exited with code 247`. Can you please tell me why? Do I need to change some setup? Or is the droplet ram too low?

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a problem of dimensions. In fact, the cluster used to have to little RAM to support all the requirements. So, after changing the droplet, everything worked fine.